# Error in library(doBy) : there is no package called ‘doBy’

Tags: r, simulation

I was trying to run one of the ndnSIM example simulation where the script compiles and executes successfully except in the end, it throws an error.

```
./build/car-relay --run=6 --distance=170
./build/car-relay --run=7 --distance=170
./build/car-relay --run=8 --distance=170
./build/car-relay --run=9 --distance=170
./build/car-relay --run=10 --distance=170
Error in library(doBy) : there is no package called ‘doBy’
Calls: suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
Execution halted
```

I am not sure if there was an issue with the installation of the 'doBy' package (which IMO, not, since it did not throw any error during the package installation). I followed these steps to install R and the required packages.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo R
install.packages ('proto')
install.packages ('ggplot2')
install.packages ('doBy')
```

I want to know how I can verify if the above packages were indeed installed correctly. With the above error, my simulation results are not complete.

Comment: Are you trying to run code on worker nodes? Do they all have the libraries installed? Was there a newline after install.packages("doBy")? `require(doBy, silent=TRUE)` is a lot like `library()` but should return false if the package is not available.

Comment: It was resolved after adding an appropriate symlink to the libgfortran.so. It did not exist before.

Comment: @AnilJ since your issue has been solved, please post that as an answer (and accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem by installing the package from its source.

1. Download the package source from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/doBy_4.5-14.tar.gz
2. Go to the R command prompt by typing 'R'
3. Issue the following command from command prompt -  install.packages("~/Downloads/doBy_4.5-14.tar.gz",  repos = NULL, type="source")

   Note: If above does not work, repeat with absolute path to the source file.

On successful installation, you should see the following message.

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘doBy’ ...
** package ‘doBy’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (doBy)
```

Comment: Link is now outdated and broken

Comment: You can find updated source of package source here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html

Comment: Also, this doesn't work if you need to use an older version of doBy.